# define 32bit on 64bit

Tags: c, gcc

i have some C files here (you don't need to know what's inside), it's in stable 32bit mode (with gcc -m32), now i want to do more 64bit (gcc -m64) it has some minor bugs\

- question:
  so how to use a 32bit C number (how 32bit works), on 64bit\
- more understandable explanation:
  i want to use 32bit in 64bit mode (-m64, there is some way works 32bit C cannot work in 64bit C)
  The most common error about this problem:
  "Cast to pointer from integer of different size"

  I really need help!\

Comment: Always use types with fixed width? `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` etc....?

Comment: *"you don't need to know what's inside"* we do if you want help with your problem.  A [mcve] that exhibits the same problem as your real code is needed.  Also: "Cast to pointer from integer of different size" means you're using integers where you should be using pointers.

Comment: Specific to "Cast to pointer from integer of different size", you should probably look into `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` from `stdint.h`. Those are the only integer types that are guaranteed to be sized appropriately to hold a pointer.

Comment: @Brian `char` is a (semi-)`integer`  and aligns fine with every other type by definition.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The problem is size, not alignment. E.g. using a 32bit integer to hold a 64bit address.

Comment: @Brian Ah, got it, it's that _"Cast to pointer from integer of different size_"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Cast to pointer from integer of different size"

Oh no. Go through your code and get rid of all casts between pointer and integer that don't convert from or to `intptr_t`, `uintptr_t`, or `ptrdiff_t`. If you convert between pointer and other-sized integer it won't work no matter how many layers of indirection you use.

Once you've done that and you still need certain-sized integers for I/O reasons use the definitions from `stdint.h`:

`int16_t`: signed 16 bit integer
`uint16_t`: unsigned 16 bit integer
`int32_t`: signed 32 bit integer
`uint32_t`: unsigned 32 bit integer
`int64_t`: signed 64 bit integer
`uint64_t`: unsigned 64 bit integer

Keep `size_t` for array sizes, don't use it in on-disk formats. It changes.

Comment: _"Keep `size_t` for array sizes"_ - unless it's supposed to be interoperable. Use fixed width types in that case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Define "interoperable".

Comment: As in _"your `size_t` does not fit in mine"_. 
`size_t` is not good for communication. It's not good for anything but local addressing situations.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Correct; hence my "don't use it in on-disk formats." Turns out to also apply to on-network formats. In-process (and except on Windows, cross-process) interop calls should use `size_t` though.

Comment: I am not sure why `ptrdiff_t` is included in the pointer casts. I suppose in practice it is always same width as `intptr_t`, but it is not specifically required to be large enough to hold all pointer values, I think.

Comment: @user17732522: Because there's so much old code that used `ptrdiff_t` for that purpose and it works on flat architectures, which is most of them. `intptr_t` is sufficiently new that it didn't exist the last time a major platform was in the case where `ptrdiff_t` didn't work, so practices didn't get updated.

Comment: @user17732522: Incidentally, I'm not aware of a 64 bit architecture where it doesn't work.